# Bounty transfer in exact dupe?

Tags: discussion

What If a Bounty'd question is duped?

Like if X question has a bounty of, lets say +100. And Y question does not have a bounty.

X is a exact dupe of Y. A mod closes it as a dupe, what happens to the +100 bounty on X?

Answer (score 5):

If a question has a bounty on it, it can't be closed as a duplicate. Closing the question with a bounty is only possible if the moderator reimburses the bounty rep and then close the question.